# C# MessageBox popup AFTER form load

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, devexpress

I'm trying to make a MessageBox appear after a form loads, but the problem is that the MessageBox appears before the actual form. 
This is the code I currently have:

```
private void LoadUsers()
{
        DataRow lockrow = DataManager.Documents.Users.LTLock.Get(UserID);
        if (lockrow != null)
        {
            DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show("Warning! Document already in use!");
        }
}
```

How could I make the MessageBox appear after the form has visibly loaded? Thanks!

Comment: you have the message box code inside your `form.load()`

Comment: @WhatsThePoint What would be a better place for it?

Comment: after the load method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Form Shown (More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx));

[image]

Code below;

```
    private void Formshown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");     
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have never used devexpress before but in winforms there is a form event `Shown` which is called immediately after the form is laoded. This is how it would be done in winforms so it would need applying to devexpress.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("someString");
    }
}
```